# Website Visited by Unresolved Ip

Tags: webserver, ddos

## My Website is flooded with unknown visiters

Awstats says that my website getting thousands of hits in few seconds.
    I am using `robots.txt` and `.htaccess`, but the problem stays there. Please help me with this. Hosting service suspend my site because of this heavy traffic from unknown IP.

Comment: I don't see a question...

Comment: He asks help with the situation

Comment: i want help with this situation, how i defend my website from this bots. @immibis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't protect your website from illegetimate requests like this. Consider moving your site behind a service which does packet scrubbing and verifies the legitimacy of the connection. One free service you could have a look at is CloudFlare.

Comment: thanks for help, if iptables will not work. I'll use cloudflare.

Comment: you want to prevent the traffic from reaching you, if you use iptables, it's generally too late.

Comment: okay so, do i need to move my website from current hosting service to cloudflare

Comment: Cloudflare is not a hosting website

Comment: okay, so how can i use cloudflare's services in my website

Comment: Did you read their website, did you read their manuals?

Comment: yes, i just read. thanks for help. i guess cloudflare will defendd my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set [iptables](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) rules in your firewall to filter the connexions you want and block the undesired ones. You can use your firewall in conjunction with [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) that will help your server (where you hosted your website) in order to update your iptables rules and reject suspicious IP addresses.